# Batch Script to copy same file

Tags: batch-file

I need your assistance, the batch script below will copy and paste same file name with different ext from source to destination folder, I want to limit the copy to only 4 files at a time, for e.g. in source folder there are 8 files namely A.txt, A.xml, B.txt, B.xml, C.txt, C.xml. When I execute, the script must copy only
A.txt, A.xml
B.txt, B.xml
to destination folder.

The script able below able to find and copy file with same name but I couldn't limit the copy.

```
set MaxLimit=2
for %%i in ("E:\Source\*.xml") do (
if exist "%%~dpni.txt" (
    copy /y "%%~i" "E:\destination"
        copy /y "%%~dpni.OCL" "E:\destination"
if %%i==%MaxLimit% exit /b 0
)
)
```

Comment: I got cancer from your code please treat me by editing your question and placing the code sections of your question in `code sample` looks like `{}`

Comment: True, edit is pending approval. if you have enough rep, approve it.

Comment: Are the files supposed to be copied randomly? is the intention to copy over single file only once? How are you intending your script to know which files have previously been copied if you're not performing that copy on all at the same time.

Comment: So you do not care about which files are copied and which are skipped? note that the order in which the files are returned (by `for`) is kind of random (actually it depends on the file system: for NTFS, the sort order is alphabetic or alpha-numeric, for FAT-32 it is random)...

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable delayed expansion with `setlocal`. Then define a counter and increment it within the loop. Then compare your limit with the counter (using `!counter!` to evaluate the variable within the loop)

```
set MaxLimit=2
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=0
for %%i in ("E:\Source\*.xml") do (
if exist "%%~dpni.txt" (
    copy /y "%%~i" "E:\destination"
        copy /y "%%~dpni.OCL" "E:\destination"
set /a counter+=1
if !counter!==%MaxLimit% exit /b 0
)
)
```